# Order Process of Amazon

Tags: amazon-product-api

We are using Submit Feed and type is `_POST_FLAT_FILE_FULFILLMENT_DATA_` to process the Amazon order.  We create a flat file that contains order ID and ship date. But when we hit Submit Feed API for orders then it gives warning message that is:

> Order cannot be fulfilled.

Where are we making a mistake?

Comment: Can you attached file data which you are sending to amazon ?

Comment: order-id ship-date                                                                         14 digit order-id dispatch date in yyyy-mm-dd format

Answer (score 0):

If your order contains more then one item then all API fields are required.

> order-id, order-item-id, quantity and ship-date

If order have only one item and you can allow only order ref & date.

**But other fields must be blank in the file at same position.**

> order-id  order-item-id   quantity    ship-date   carrier-code    carrier-name    tracking-number ship-method

You need to send other fields value Null in the file.

This may help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We will test it.

Comment: It gives error while hit submit feed order api of Amazon and the error is Warning order cannot be fulfilled. The flat file which we created for order processing of Amazon is in this form order-id order-item-id quantity ship-date carrier-code carrier-name tracking-number ship- method.  We have inserted only order-id and ship date(order Dispatch date is inserted and date format is yyyy-mm-dd) and other fields are blank. After that it gives Warning order can't be fulfilled.